# Several TextViews change to line where no space in screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am having the next code and I am trying to get a jump of line where there is no space left in the screen:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions_check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_check1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions_check2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_check2"
            android:textColor="#00f" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions_check3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_check3" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions_check4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_check4" 
            android:textColor="#00f" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

What I am doing wrong? There is any way to get that?

Image:
[image: Error]

Comment: if you want one below the other change orientation  `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by  "I am trying to get a jump of line". But i guess you need all your widgets one below the other

So change the orientation of your `LinearLayout`

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: What I need is all the widgets one on the right of the previous one, but if the top of the screen is reached I would like to continue on the line below.

Comment: @MarcForn you can use a relative layout. Can you show pictorially how it should look coz your question is not very clear.  "but if the top of the screen is reached I would like to continue on the line below" is very unclear.

Comment: @MarcForn LinearLayout places the widget linearly either horizontally or vertically depending on the orientation set. So i am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have attached an image of the problem that I have. What I would like to happen is that "Privacy Policy" appears automatically to the next line.

Comment: @MarcForn you need to use another layout or use relative layout. You also need to take care of different screen sizes coz device screen size changes so if you put "Privacy Policy" below in one device in another you may need to put "Terms of Service" also below . I would suggest you to have just` android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

<CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/terms_and_conditions_check"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center_vertical"
  android:text="terms_and_conditions_check1 terms_and_conditions_check2 terms_and_conditions_check3 terms_and_conditions_check4" />
```